# Creating a Texture2D array with CPU write access

Tags: directx, directx-10

I'm trying to create a Texture2D array with CPU write access. In detail, the code I'm using looks like this:

```
D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;

texDesc.Width               = 32;
texDesc.Height              = 32;
texDesc.MipLevels           = 1;
texDesc.ArraySize           = 2;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Count    = 1;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality  = 0;
texDesc.Usage               = D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
texDesc.CPUAccessFlags      = CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
texDesc.Format              = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
texDesc.BindFlags           = D3D10_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
texDesc.MiscFlags           = 0;

ID3D10Texture2D* texture2D;
CHECK_SUCCESS(device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, NULL, &texture2D));
```

This, however, fails with E_INVALIDARG. Creating a 3D texture with the same dimensions (ie 32x32x2) and parameters works well, but is not desired in this case.
Does anyone know why this setup would not be valid?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an array of D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA of length texDesc.ArraySize as input for the second parameter of CreateTexture2D().

For more help see this [example](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14507/loading-a-texture2d-array-in-directx11).

Comment: I know that, and with ArraySize equal to 1 this will work. In this case, however, I need a texture array (ie multiple slices) with write access.

Comment: In the example you referred to in the edit, providing a subresource pointer makes sense as he is trying to create an immutable texture array. However, I want to create a dynamic buffer as I want to be able to update the content of the textures multiple times. In conclusion, I don't need an immutable buffer and thus no provided data. Yet, I tested it and still get the same error (even when providing the described data).